# Why are these Landsat composite exports vastly different sizes from GEE when they shouldn't be?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat-8, composite

I'm trying to export annual composites of Landsat data in Google Earth Engine of two regions of interest (below )

```
var LakeRegion = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-81.30699128350481, 28.4505466197819],
          [-81.31076783379778, 28.330338473924865],
          [-81.2348935051845, 28.32761862398309],
          [-81.23077363213763, 28.4505466197819]]]),
    geometry = 
    /* color: #00ffff */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[78.61838685215967, 12.152351725489272],
          [78.61838685215967, 12.046943299360715],
          [78.69735108555811, 12.046943299360715],
          [78.69735108555811, 12.152351725489272]]], null, false),
    ls8SR = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR");
```

These polygons are nearly the same size. However, when I run my script (below), exporting a single year of data for the first region, LakeRegion, takes less than 30 seconds to run and outputs a tif of 2.7MB while the second region, geometry, takes ~2 hours to run and outputs multiple tifs that are collectively about 80MB. What is the cause of this?

```
function mask(img){
  var m = img.select('pixel_qa');
  img = img.mask(m.leftShift(14).rightShift(15).eq(1));
  return img;
}

function lsCloudMask(img) {
  var mask = img.select('pixel_qa').bitwiseAnd(3).or(img.select('pixel_qa').bitwiseAnd(5));
  return img.updateMask(mask);
}

var jsonCoordString = geometry.toGeoJSON();


for (var start_year = 2013; start_year <= 2021; start_year++)
{
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(start_year,01,01);
  var sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry)).filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,startDate.advance(1,'year')));
  sr = sr.map(mask);
  sr = sr.map(lsCloudMask)
  sr = sr.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());
  
  Map.addLayer(sr.select([3,2,1]).clip(geometry),{min: [0,0,0], max: [2000,2000,2000]});

  
  Export.image.toDrive({image: sr.select([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]),
                       description: 'Nona'+ start_year.toString(),
                       folder: 'CLASprojects',
                       fileNamePrefix: 'Nona_' + start_year.toString(),
                       region: jsonCoordString,
                       crs: 'EPSG:32719',
                       maxPixels: 10000000000,
                       scale: 30})
  
  
  
}
```

Note for above code: I have it running on geometry, I change it when I run it on LakeRegion.

Comment: Is there a way to bump this up to try and increase chances of someone seeing this and knowing the answer?